# How to prove: EVERY strong pseudoprime is a Euler pseudoprime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pseudoprimes

I know when $n \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, the Euler pseudo prime is a strong pseudoprime, and that strong pseudoprime is a Euler pseudoprime.

But I don't know how to prove that every strong pseudoprime is a Euler pseudoprime.

I think that if we can prove that "if  $n \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, the strong pseudoprime is a Euler pseudoprime."

Anyway I want to know how to prove [the question in the] title.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the definitions. What does it mean that $n$ is a strong (Fermat) pseudoprime to base $a$, and what does it mean that $n$ is an Euler pseudoprime to base $a$?

Comment: Strong pseudoprime is composite which passed miller rabin test

Comment: Not just fermat pseudoprime and i know the definitions of them

Comment: You seem to have misinterpreted the parentheses. I didn't mean that strong pseudoprime would be the same as Fermat pseudoprime, I added the name Fermat to distinguish it from e.g. strong Lucas pseudoprimes or strong Frobenius pseudoprimes. If you know the definitions, then it should be clear that being a strong (Fermat, or Miller-Rabin if you prefer) pseudoprime to base $a$ implies being an Euler pseudoprime to base $a$. If not, _what_ is not clear?

Answer (score 2):

When someone says that $n$ is an "Euler pseudoprime" to base $a$, they might mean one of two things.

Some authors mean simply $a^{n-1}\equiv \pm 1\mod n$.  If that's what you mean, then the commenters are correct: just check the definitions.  But that's probably not what you mean because this isn't *equivalent* to strong pseudoprime-ness.

Other authors mean $a^{n-1}\equiv \left(\frac{a}{n}\right)\mod n$.  (This is sometimes referred to as an Euler-Jacobi pseudoprime.)  I'm guessing you mean this because you refer to the $n\equiv 3(4)$ case of EJ PSPs and strong PSPs being the same.  The $n\equiv 1(4)$ case is trickier.  See the discussion starting on page 1009 of [Pomerance, Selfridge, and Wagstaff's 1980 paper](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper25.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

“Pseudoprime” means a^(n-1) = 1 modulo n. There is another property of primes that allows filtering out composites: If x^2 = 1 modulo n and n is prime then x = +/- 1.

Miller-Rabin uses this: Calculate a^(n-1) by raising a to an odd power, then squaring as often as needed. Miller-Rabin checks that *none* of the squarings produces a result of 1 mod n by squaring a number that isn’t +/- 1. Euler checks only that the *last* squaring doesn’t do this. So if you define Euler-Pseudoprimes like that then it filters out fewer composites and leaves more pseudoprimes than Miller-Rabin.

And if n = 3 mod 4, then n-1 is an odd number multiplied by 2^1, so Miller-Rabin has only one squaring to check, and Miller-Rabin and Euler test are absolutely identical in this case.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).